# Where should I put apiKey before publishing android application in Android market

Tags: android, google-play, sign, api-key

I have signed and get this kind of code:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="0vzxVMvckBdI64O0FdGSRXawhfAlw"
             />
```

Then I put it to main.xml, under the . I run the project, it force close. The error is that XML can not find MapView. But I have add the library below. Moreover, I have test with google API Vitual machine, and it does not work too. Then I add Internet permission, and add:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

under the  in manifest, but it still does not work.
Could anybody tell me clearly step by step what I have to do, I am in a mess now and I can understand want to do next.

Before signed the apiKey, my application run well. Anybody help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea. Why does it force close? Pro-tip: any time you type the words "force close" into a SO question, include the stack trace.

Comment: What error do you get? Post a StackTrace. Also, your question title and your problem are kind of different which might hinder people from helping you. Post a stacktrace, and edit to to something like "MapView causes a force close".

Comment: Ok, i will edit the question. But first of all, I want to ask about the step u guys usually do after publishing. Can u tell me that?

Answer (score 0):

If you app worked well before signing your app then its the problem of you map Api key.
You can get a temporary Maps API Key based on your debug certificate, but before you publish your application, you must register for a new Key based on your release certificate and update references in your MapViews accordingly.

use adb to install the apk on your device/emulator (adb install app.apk). Don't forget to uninstall the debug version first, otherwise the signature difference will prevent the installation

EDIT:
When using GoogleMaps for Android, you need two keys - debug and release.

The "debug" key is kind of a misleading term. This key is also to be used when you develop the app in Eclipse. So essentially, use the debug key for development, testing, debugging.

When you're ready to launch the app to Market, set the android:debuggable="false" in the AndroidManifest.xml and use the Signed API key.

When using the signed API key, the MapView will show up ONLY when the app is installed from the Android Market. So, installing the app from Eclipse (Run As, Debug As, etc) or command line (adb install) won't show the MapView. Rest assured, once the app is in the Market - you download it and the MapView will show up.

With the signed API key, if you deploy the app from Eclise, you will get a "Server returned 3, IOProcessing Exception 26" as a warning - just ignore it.

Note: Also ensure there are no duplicate instances of the same MapView. If your app needs "x" no. of MapViews, generate "x" no. of new signed keys (one for each MapView) since GoogleMaps has a query limit for a single MapView instance.

For getting both the keys, follow the steps for [Obtaining API keys for GoogleMaps on Android.](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Comment: could you explain to me, after I got the api Key. What do I have to do step by step. Thanks a lot.